# Cannot write redirection symbol(>>) to text file using nmake

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, nmake

I have a make file which outputs some data to a text file. Commands shown below:

```
@echo HOURS >> 123.txt
@echo MINUTES >> 123.txt
@echo SECONDS >> 123.txt
```

As of now the 123.txt file contains
HOURS
MINUTES
SECONDS

I would like to append a text such as >> to the end of the 123.txt file. How to do it. I tried with the command `@echo >> >> 123.txt` but it is not successful, a blank line is written to 123.txt file. The desired output file should be:
HOURS
MINUTES
SECONDS  >>
Can anyone help me on this how to add ">>" to end of the file.

Thanks

Comment: `@echo SECONDS \>\> >> 123.txt ` should work

Comment: Or `@echo SECONDS '>>' >> 123.txt`

Comment: @Najzero this is not working

Comment: @reinierpost ">>" works but it writes the data in quotes.Adding that command gives SECONDS ">>" but not SECONDS >>

Comment: What is your shell, `CMD` or `sh`?

Comment: @reinierpost its CMD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do this:

```
@echo HOURS >> 123.txt
@echo MINUTES >> 123.txt
@echo SECONDS^>^> >> 123.txt
```

'^' is the escape character for CMD